# Typescript - how to implement part of a dependency's interface?

Tags: typescript, winston

I'm trying to create my own logger class. It contains a reference to `winston.Logger` as `this.logger`. Winston's logger is defined to have methods like these:

```
    error: LeveledLogMethod;
    warn: LeveledLogMethod;
// etc...
```

`LeveledLogMethod` is defined as:

```
  interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (message: string, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
    (message: string, meta: any, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
    (message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger;
    (infoObject: object): Logger;
  }
```

For my logger, I only want it to support e.g. `debug`, `info`, and `error` methods - but - I also don't care for these methods to implement all of `LeveledLogMethod`. So, I'll define my own interface for my log methods:

```
interface LogMethod {
  (message: string): void;
  // (message: string, meta: any): void;
  // (message: string, ...meta: any[]): void;
  (infoObject: object): void;
}
```

To keep it simple, I've commented out part of what I want to implement. Still, this much is enough to error out. Basically, my `LogMethod` interface is a subset of winston's `LeveledLogMethod`.

However, when I try to implement my `LogMethod`s like this:

```
  public debug: LogMethod = (arg: string | object) => {
    this.logger.debug(arg);
  };
  // `this.logger` is a `winston.Logger` and `this.logger.debug` is a `LeveledLogMethod`.
```

I get:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(infoObject: object): Logger', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object'.
```

But I know that this should work as regardless of whether `arg` is a `string` or an `object`, it matches one of the overloads defined in `LeveledLogMethod`.

How can I get Typescript's compiler to let me do this short of `// @ts-ignore`ing it or casting `arg` to either `string` or `object`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `arg` should exactly match one of the `LeveledLogMethod` signatures, but it matches neither first nor second. Although the code is correct, the compiler looks on it from a different point of view.

I can suggest you add a type check instead of a cast:

```js
public debug: LogMethod = (arg: string | object) => {
  if (typeof arg === 'string') {
    this.logger.debug(arg);
  } else {
    this.logger.debug(arg);
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gcwMIEMA2aBGKDGBrKAXigAoBKIgPigG8BfAKAEsA7YCAJwDNdp4EEnWo2ZtOPHHwgA3CGggATfgFkIwABZwFtBlFIBbCAGcjKQQC4oR4B1YIANFBzosuPJf6oM2fGQ%20JBDgBuXQNjUwsrGztHQ2AUSxQWEEdnbzd-ZBcfPD9YAM4QvRJDEzMIS2tbFgcoADoGuISoJJAAbQBdPP5AotJWLjgAeUwAKwgcYEs4MYngboLghhFWdm5eKAB1Vms4Fh6hGlC9Tg44Dg8ZOUUVNU0FPr0AdxQOFkvZeSVEVQ0tEJWYnWknyCF%209x0xVKEQqUWqCDy0jgTAeoRIA2Gs0m0yx80sSJRAIYDBwaBQJigyhABw4kKgYFs0hQ7CgaEWAEJLNsWLt9osQqEwABXTBoJg4KCnc6ZcFaIikV4ISrRGpQAA%20UBm40mFEI1COej0TC4pFAkDgJsVREIxAA5FU7LaKAbDXoNEwjHU2QJOHUpRwSIqyI8oHRJWgjNAXa73Z7vYE-RwzgGgyHGHo6ESgA)